Extremely slow terminal input is back on Ubuntut 22.04
I ran into this problem before and posted about it, apparently others were having the issue too.
I ran the suggested fix and everything was fine, now it's starting again and I don't know what to do.

I've also applied the mutter fix described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1509474/426149
And it was resolved for awhile, but it's happening again for me as well.
